# How to display a query from a database in SQLite to an activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an app that includes a chronometer and the time is saved into a SQLite database, I want to use those times saved to get the average time result in a textview in another activity, is there anyway to do that? I'm new to programming in general and I haven't find a way to do this. For what I've seen the query SELECT AVG(time) FROM TIMETABLE works well on the database Inspector, I just need to get that result on a text view.

Comment: Hi, please provide some code showing what you tried doing so far. It is customary to have relevant code when you submit a question. The lack of code might be one of the reasons for receiving down votes from the community.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use those times saved to get the average time result in a textview in another activity, is there anyway to do that?

Yes, without doubt. Although whether you mean actually saved e.g. in the database or just mean extracted would make the process different. Probably just the latter as there is likely no need to save the result permanently *(see next part)*.

> to get the average time result in a textview in another activity.

This could be extracted directly from/by the activity there appears to be little need to save pass and extract the average in the parent activity. But there again, if you mean an average from a set rather than the entire data *(`SELECT AVG(time) FROM TIMETABLE` being the entire data)* whilst a set would be if a `WHERE` clause were applied, then the drivers/parameters for the `WHERE` may be required to be passed from the parent activity to the child activity, this can be accomplished by adding Intent extras prior to starting the child activity and then extracting them in the child activity.)

In either case you can:-

1. instantiate an instance of the Database Helper (sub class of SQLiteOpenHelper using the Context from the child activity)
2. use the `rawQuery` or prefereably the `query` method to return a `Cursor` using/building *(which the query method does on your behalf)* the appropriate `SELECT`
3. use the Cursor's `moveToFirst` method, testing that it returns true *(just in case as a single row should always be returned if the query works)*
4. extracting the value *(probably as String using the
   Cursor's `getString` method)*
5. if the movetoFirst returns false *(very unlikely)* set the String to an appropriate value to indicate nothing obtained/extracted.
6. in either case use the Cursor's close method *(too many open (as in not closed) Cursor can cause an exception (something like 1000))*.
7. set the text of the Textview (could be done as part of 4 and 6)

**Example**

here's a very basic example that:-

When started enters the first activity (MainActivity), prepares the TextView named **clickMe** by allowing it to be clicked and start the 2nd activity (MainActivity2), gets an instance of the DatabaseHelper, adds some rows to the **chrono** table, (cheats and changes the clickMe textview to show the average).

If the **clickMe** Textview is clicked the 2nd activity is started and ...

The 2nd activity gets it's instance of the database helper and sets the TextView with the average.

Nothing else for brevity (can go back using back button).

**The code**

The Database Helper **DBHelper.java**

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DBNAME = "chrono.db"; /* name of the database file - change as fits */
    private static final int DBVERSION = 1; /* version of the database - best to use 1 at first */
    public static final String CHRONO_TABLENAME = "_chrono"; /* name of the table - change as fits underscore at start means no clash with SQLite keywords */
    public static final String CHRONO_TABLE_ID_COLUMN = BaseColumns._ID; /* make the ID column use the android standard column name for the ID column */
    public static final String CHRONO_TABLE_TIME_COLUMN = "time"; /* name of the time column */
    private static SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static volatile DBHelper instance_of_DBHelper;

    private DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase(); /* Force initial open of the database when called - optional */
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + CHRONO_TABLENAME + "(" +
                CHRONO_TABLE_ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                CHRONO_TABLE_TIME_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0" +
                ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public static DBHelper getInstance_of_DBHelper(Context context) {
        if (instance_of_DBHelper == null) {
            instance_of_DBHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return instance_of_DBHelper;
    }

    public long insertChronoRow(long timeAsLong) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CHRONO_TABLE_TIME_COLUMN,timeAsLong);
        return db.insert(CHRONO_TABLENAME,null,cv);
    }

    public String getAverageTime() {
        String rv = "Cannot get Average????";
        Cursor csr = db.query(
                CHRONO_TABLENAME,
                new String[]{"avg("+ CHRONO_TABLE_TIME_COLUMN +") AS "+ CHRONO_TABLE_TIME_COLUMN +""},
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(CHRONO_TABLE_TIME_COLUMN));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

- Note this utilises singleton approach so the same instance is used throughout.

MainActivity's layout **activity_main.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLICK ME!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The first activity **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView clickMe;
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        clickMe = this.findViewById(R.id.clickme);
        // Setup the TextView so that if clicked it starts the 2nd activity
        clickMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("UNIQUE_KEY_FROM_MAINACTIVITY_VALUE1","a suitable values to be passed to the started activity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance_of_DBHelper(this); /* Get an Instance of the Database helper */
        dbHelper.insertChronoRow(60); /* 60 time units */
        dbHelper.insertChronoRow(100); /* 100 time units */
        dbHelper.insertChronoRow(110); /* 110 time untis */
        clickMe.setText("CLICK ME!! - P.S. Average is now " + dbHelper.getAverageTime());
    }
}
```

The layout for the 2nd activity **activity_main2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/average"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Average as yet - if you see this then something is not right">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally the 2nd activity **MainActivity2.java**

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView average;
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        average = this.findViewById(R.id.average);
        dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance_of_DBHelper(this);
        average.setText(dbHelper.getAverageTime());
    }
}
```

**Result**

When started :-

[image]

When the TextView (as highlighted in the previous image) is clicked and the 2nd activity is started :-

[image]